# Only remove entries that have the exact same text in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I am currently making a table with the datatables plugin, I have made a filter using a combo box to get the results that match certain criteria. What I am having trouble with is to remove certain rows containing a text. For example:

In my column I will have this text in the row:

```html
Dividend (Full (100%) Scrip Div available)
<br>
Dividend
<br>
Code Change
<br>
Dividend (Full (100%) Scrip Div available)
<br>
Consolidation
<br>
Dividend
<br>
Dividend
```

I want to remove all those that only have Dividend as a full word, the others should be kept.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
titleColumn.search('^(?:(?!Dividend).)*$', true, false).draw();
```

What it does right now is to remove all the rows that contains the word Dividend, but I want to remove only the ones that have the full word and nothing else.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you want to allow for white-space in the row (and thus remove, e.g., `"Dividend     "`)?

Comment: Hi, not really, the white spaces are removed before, so just need to remove the rows that contain "Dividend" any other words that have Dividend and some extra text must stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is exact string match .You can use this as a reference. This will check for exact match and then you can remove it or whatever is your logic.

```
var reg = /^Dividend$/;
console.log(reg .test('Dividenda')); // false
console.log(reg .test('ba Dividend')); // false
console.log(reg .test('Dividend (Full (100%) Scrip Div available)')); // false
console.log(reg .test('Dividend a')); //false
console.log(reg .test('Dividend')); //true
```

In your case:

```
titleColumn.search(reg, true, false).draw();
```

Comment: Hi @Cyclotron3x3, I just found out how to do it, but I got it thanks to you and dave. It works correctly if I send it like this:

    titleColumn.search('^(?:(?!^Dividend$).)*$', true, false).draw();

Comment: @Linkavich14 I think I found a simpler version of your regex. Works for me in Perl anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, we wish to look for the word `Dividend` bound by the start and end of line. However, because you wish to *exclude* these lines we use a lookaround:

```
titleColumn.search('^(?!Dividend$)', true, false).draw();
```

Comment: Hi Dave, what I need is to remove the ones that have the full word Dividend and has nothing else besides the word and keep all the others

Comment: I realised that, but wasn't paying attention to the effect of the search. I'll adjust my answer.